# PyGtk Application Logo/Icon

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, logo

I'm starting to develop some apps. I'm reading through [python gtk](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) documentation. It's all going fine but I have one question. How does Ubuntu find application logos? Like the one it displays in the dash and stuff, and how can I add one to my test app.

Comment: Your keyword to search with: `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [.desktop file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) and put the reference to your icon there.

Dash and the launcher will pick it up.